# Is it possible to use vim with the mouse

Tags: vim, editor, mouse, vi

Is it possible to use vim with the mouse?
If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With GVim, you can select text and move the cursor, and select menu options with the mouse. Copy and paste, by right-clicking etc... But I guess this misses the point of using VIM.

Answer (score 11):

You can enable the mouse with `:set mouse=a` (The letter 'a' means enable it in all modes)

Answer (score 5):

You can map certain actions to mouse left click and right click. And there are plenty of already mapped actions to work with ctags and other things.

```
:help mouse-using
```